# How can I put an image in, magnify and minimize it?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I need to put an png to my application, magnify, minimize and moving it, as in this [picture](http://oi58.tinypic.com/15x4jyp.jpg) , I don't know if there was a limit or not, I don't know how!

Help please  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://code.google.com/p/platform-features-talk-io-2013/source/browse/photoviewer/) the official photoviewer demo from IO last year to get you started. Or if you'd rather work with an external library check out [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). I believe they both have the functionality you are looking for.